# codeigniter form sql error

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Something wrong is here. I get error on submit: this need to be simple drop down option where you can select between 2 tip of...

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ORDER BY int_displayorder ASC at line 1 SELECT var_price_label1,var_price_label2,var_price1,var_price2 FROM dis_activity where int_glcode= ORDER BY int_displayorder ASC
>
> Filename: /home/discou60/public_html/beta/modules/reservationleads/models/reservationleads_model.php
>   Line Number: 1337

```
$SQL = $this->db->query("SELECT var_price_label1,var_price_label2,var_price1,var_price2 FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "activity where int_glcode=$tagid ORDER BY int_displayorder ASC");
    $RS = $SQL->Result();
    $Html = "";
    $Html .= "<select name='int_no_of_people' id='int_no_of_people' ><option value=''> Choose Your charter</option>";
    foreach ($RS as $Row) {
        $selected = "";
        if (!empty($tagid) && $tagid == $Row->int_glcode) {
            $selected = "selected='selected'";
        }
         $Html .= "<option $selected value='" . $Row->var_price1 . "'>" . $Row->var_price_label1 . "</option>";
         $Html .= "<option  value='" . $Row->var_price2 . "'>" . $Row->var_price_label2 . "</option>";
    }


    $Html .= "</select>";

    return $Html;
```

Comment: Except that there is no `ORDER BY` in the code you have shown...

Comment: `where int_glcode= ORDER BY` there's an error somewhere for sure. where/how it's generated, I've no idea. so this part `where int_glcode=` is missing something that's not being populated.

Comment: So your `$tagid` variable is empty. You should check its value before you add it to the query.

Comment: `where int_glcode=$tagid` is where it's failing. `$tagid` isn't being populated. It might need to be quoted; hard to say.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: @jeroen should've put your comment as an answer ;-)

Comment: `$tagid = "whatever"; if(isset($tagid) && !empty($tagid)){ $SQL = $this->db->query(...) } else { echo "Failed"; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check if `$tagid` is not empty, and replace the sql string as follows

```
...where int_glcode = '".$tagid."' ORDER BY int_displayorder ASC...
```

Comment: same applies here as per what I left in another answer.

Comment: ELECT var_price_label1,var_price_label2,var_price1,var_price2 FROM dis_activity where int_glcode=\''.73.'\' ORDER BY int_displayorder ASC

Answer (score 0):

The error is *explicitly* and *exactly* telling you the problem...

> ... where int_glcode= ORDER BY int_displayorder ASC ...

You forgot to put a *value* in the `WHERE` clause comparison.  Apparently `$tagid` is empty (or at least doesn't have a meaningful string representation) when you build that string.  (Which is kind of a blessing in disguise, because `$tagid` could contain *anything* and has a potential for SQL injection.)

Comment: that's already been established in comments, quite heavily I might add.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Maybe I'm missing your point but... So?  This is the exact cause of the error.  Maybe if the OP provides more context we can arrive at *why* `$tagid` isn't being populated, but the question being asked is to simply explain the error message.  This is an explanation of exactly that.

Comment: if any of the answers given so far receive a downvote, I'd like y'all to know beforehand that it would not have come from me; *just saying*.

Comment: { $tagid = $this->input->get_post('fk_location');} is same  like int_glcode

Comment: @AleksandarMilisavljevic: And where is that code happening?  How have you confirmed that a valid value is being found?  When you debug this, what is the actual value of `$tagid` when you declare that SQL string?